# Javascript code analyzer open source code or plugin

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I have written an API and defined a method which a user needs to call on a certain condition. Suppose a user is creating a video app then he should implement mute function in his code (which is defined in a javascript API or file). Now I am looking for a code analyzer by which i can check wether he has implemented this (in his JS file) in a correct way. According to me I think this will be a custom rule and I want to make this project in Java, so that I can take the source code( Which is a js file or html file) and do this analysis on that source code.

So is there any code analyzer tool available ?

how can i compile this idea?

And what are the possible way?

Many many thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). It will fit your needs. It was a lot of out of the box tasks like:

```
<module name="VisibilityModifier">
    <property name="packageAllowed" value="true"/>
</module>
```

But you can [extend](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) it.

You write your custom rules in Java, but it check anything. In our project, we use it e.g. to check the vadility of xml, jsp, ... files.

Comment: As i added in the answer: rules are written in java, but can apply on anything.

Comment: Sorry but suppose i want to implement Checkstyle for some flat text file so is it also possible with costume rule?

Comment: Yes. But you will probably still need a javascript unit test tool like PhantomJs/CasperJs, ... to check if your javascript code executes correctly.

Comment: No basically i just want to check some norms which is defined by me like is developer called Mute funtion before starting screensaver